How do I get the current Time in CAPL?
I am writing testresults I get into an .csv now I want to get a new .csv when I repeat the test.
my idea was to set the Timestamp at the End of the name of my .csv to tell them appart but I cant figure out how to do that.
my code is as follows:
setFilePath("C:XXXX", 2);
logFile = openFileWrite("Results.csv", 2);

if (tf1succes == 1) 
{
  snprintf(results, 1024, "TF01 was succesfull. \n");
  filePutString(results, 1024, logFile);       
}
else
{
  snprintf(results, 1024, "TF01 was not succesfull. \n");
  filePutString(results, 1024, logFile);       
}

fileClose(logFile);

getTime() - didnt work
getSystemTime() - didnt work

For someone looking at this later: the solution is to use getLocalTimeString the right way.
getLocalTimeString(timeactual);

will fill the current time and date into your variable:
char timeactual[27];


Extensive research in CANoe's documentation will lead to:
getLocalTime which will get you an array of integers denoting seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, and so on.
Or even
getLocalTimeString which will get you a formatted datetime string.

I found that too yesterday but CAPL says: Error   1053 at (36,16): Unknown symbol 'getLocalTimeString'.

Found it in "Programming with CAPL" from Vector itself but thats from 2004

Something to think about is, are you sure you want your files to have this whole thing added to them : "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" ?  Because you could do the same thing by converting that to the UNIXTIMESTAMP so that for example a file called DATA-2024-08-19 08:00:00.CSV could be the converted to Unix Time stamp with the same value and the file would be DATA-1723819826.CSV ... unless you want a space and a really long file name, perhaps this might be a good thing to consider.  The downside is i don't think its native to capl but you could for sure implement some code to handle it.

if you know the signal timing when it is receipting and transferring use the following function:
getSignalTime(pass that signal here)

